# Are my controller methods executed async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

Based on `IHttpActionResult` I created a base class (simplified):

```
  public abstract class BaseHttpActionResult<T> : IHttpActionResult
  {
    protected readonly HttpRequestMessage Request;

    internal abstract Task<T> ExecuteAsync();

    protected BaseHttpActionResult(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
      Request = request;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      try
      {
        T data = await ExecuteAsync();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        HttpStatusCode statusCode;
        if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
          // 403
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        }
        else if (ex is ObjectNotFoundException)
        {
          // 404
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
        else if (ex is DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
          // 409
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
        }
        else
        {
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }

        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode,
                                           $"{GetType().Name} - {ex.GetType().Name}: '{ex.Message}'",
                                           ex);
      }
    }
  }
```

One simple implementation of this could be like this:

```
  public class SampleResult : BaseHttpActionResult<string>
  {
    private readonly IDoAsyncStuffService service;

    public SampleResult(IDoAsyncStuffService service, HttpRequestMessage request) : base(request)
    {
      this.service = service;
    }

    internal override async Task<string> ExecuteAsync()
    {
      return await service.GetSomethingAsync();
    }
  }
```

And then the usage in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(RouteConfig.Get.Sample)]
public SampleResult GetSampleResult()
{
  return new SampleResult(service, Request);
}
```

However as you can see my controller method now lacks the `async` keyword and also it returns only a `SampleResult` instead of a `Task<SampleResult>`.

So my question is now:

Is still everything executed async, even though my controller method is not declared as such and does not return a task?

Or do I need to do something differently?

Comment: Well, your controller method does not execute the async operation at all. It just returns an instance of the class that will as soon as you call it's ExecuteAsync method.

Comment: Well as the other guys mentioned, apparently the method is executed and even async (because it implements `IHttpActionResult` )

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what exactly *is* your controller, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite its appearance, `async` is an *implementation detail* rather than part of the signature of the method. It's just a particular *means* for you to author a function that returns a `Task` that represents ongoing work.

It's perfectly possible to author a method that returns a `Task` that represents ongoing work without using the `async` and `await` keywords. Such a method is indistinguishable from your method, so far as the caller is concerned.

So, yes, *when* your `ExecuteAsync` method is called it will be as async as it is capable of being.

Comment: While all this is true, IMHO, it has nothing to do with `public SampleResult GetSampleResult()`. This one is completely not asynchronous. It returns an instance of a class that provides an async API. Calls to that are a different story. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, `GetSampleResult` itself is synchronous (and trivial) but then the OP is building on the ASP.Net infrastructure of returning an `IHttpActionResult` which appears to perform the real work so I was focussing on the method that appears to do the substantial work rather than the trivial one.

Comment: I understand that. I just wonder if OP is also aware of this. Or what exactly he considers to be "a controller method".

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation makes sense and confirms most of my own thoughts already, I just wanted to be sure that what I was doing is correct and that I can use the benefits of async/await.

Answer (score 3):

The `GetSampleResult` itself will not be executed async because there is nothing async in it, but when executing the result, that will execute asynchronously as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter that your controller method is not `async`, `ExecuteAsync` method will still be executed asynchronously.

When a request comes in, ASP.NET takes one of its thread pool threads and assigns it to that request. When it encounters asynchronous part of the code request thread will be returned to the thread pool while the asynchronous call is in progress. When the asynchronous call returns, ASP.NET takes one of its thread pool threads and reassigns it to that request.

Comment: Useful article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx